# How to clean up x-axis values in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=220)

data.plot(kind='bar', y='p_1', ax=ax, color ='red')
data.plot(kind='bar', y='value_1', ax=ax, color ='blue')

ax.set_xlabel("Index values")
ax.set_ylabel("Value 1 / P_1")


#ax.legend(["Value 1, P_1"])
plt.title('Line plots')

plt.show()
```

Which returns the following graph:
[image: Graph In Question]

As you can see the x-axis has some crazy stuff going on. I was wondering what went wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for I think `plt.xticks(positions, labels)`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=220)

### used this to generate and test a new plot
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
    [np.arange(50),
    np.arange(50)]
).T).rename(columns={0: 'value_1', 1:'p_1'})
print(data)

data.plot(kind='bar', y='p_1', ax=ax, color ='red')
data.plot(kind='bar', y='value_1', ax=ax, color ='blue')

ax.set_xlabel("Index values")
ax.set_ylabel("Value 1 / P_1")

### added new code here
ticks = range(0, 50, 5)
labels = ticks
plt.xticks(ticks, labels)

#ax.legend(["Value 1, P_1"])
plt.title('Line plots')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(value_1)+1, 5), np.arange(0, len(value_1)+1, 5) )
```

creates a tick every 5 intervals and corresponding label.

Comment: you need to also change the labels otherwise it numbers wrong